# Google account without gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a google account for G+ Picasa and some other services i like to use. 
What i do not like is gmail it is i believe complete junk. 
Be it as it may.
I have purchased a new android device and wanted to sign in to buy some apps, using my already existing google account. 
But alas, i cannot do it without creating a gmail account it looks like.
That is just crazy i have an account, if they really want to they can trace what i do already. Why do i need to have junkmail ... ehh.. i mean gmail also.

Is there a way around this? Please help. I have 14 days to return my phone so need to find a way to do it before that or abandon it.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no other way. You must have a Gmail account to download from Google Play Store.

From their [site](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2521798):

> To use Google Play to download Android apps, you'll need to have a
>   Google account with a Google email (either Gmail or a Google-hosted
>   domain) associated with your phone or tablet.

If you don't like Gmail, you don't have to use it. Just disable the syncing for emails, and you'll be fine.

Comment: You can also disable the gmail app in `Applications` so it wont appear and bug you. But as stated above you have to have a google mail.

Comment: I think notifications are sent to your gmail account when you make purchases in the Play store (unless an alternative email can be set??), so it might not be wise to scrub gmail as much as possible? Perhaps you could set up an automated forwarder in your gmail (from googleplay-noreply@google.com ?), or collect your gmail via POP3/IMAP? What if you dont log into your gmail account for 9 months?

Comment: The real issue is that if i set up gmail on my account it makes that my primary email and uses that name as my username. I don't like that, i want to keep my own email as primary. I will have a think. But it's really annoying.
Maybe i should setup a separate account just to download my apps. But then i will need to keep track of it. Ahhahaha... it's just sooooo annoying. i wish they would just let me use my account as it is.

Comment: @zawisza Yeah, just create a new account for it, if it really bothers you. For the record, I only get notifications from Google Play when I pay for something, nothing else. I think I got newsletters about music recommendations, but I unsubscribed. I don't get any spam from Google.

Comment: Btw, if you dislike google services, play store is not your only option. There are alternative legit markets also that you can download like Amazon app store, Appbrain, SlideME etc. But then, you have to register another account

Comment: Tried Amazon App Store. That works fine. But then realized i can't use my G+ app without the account. :(
Yeah i know, it's weird i like G+ but i don't like GMail.
But it's just the way it is.
I think i will be taking the phone back. Thanks for all your help Everyone.

Answer (score 3):

## New facts as of 2015

- You can create a Google account *without* gmail
- You can *remove* gmail from your google account

[On android, is there any way to sign into Google Play without also signing into Gmail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75298/on-android-is-there-any-way-to-sign-into-google-play-without-also-signing-into)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting up a separate google account for using the play store, which you use only for that purpose.  This is more generally a useful, if insufficient response to a lot of google's connect-everything strategy.

Answer (score -2):

There is 1mobile.com. I install this to get most of my APKs. Then, I delete it because it is like goo play and wants to run all the time. If I want another APK, I reinstall it, get the app, and uninstall.

Then, there is also:

- gooapk.net
- gizom's
- appsapk
- papk
- apktop
- etc

Gooapk should keep you busy for a day or two.

I'm getting a divorce from googirl myself. And "oh looky", a sign-in with googirl for posting on a how to NOT use googirl blog. Awesome!