# Can't use Google Account on Android 2.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-account

I have an LG Phoenix with Android 2.3 and I just recently did a factory reset, and now when I go to add my Google account, it won't let me add it. After I entered in my username (...@outlook.com) and my password, it says that "...@outlook.com does not use gmail". Then it offered me a couple suggestions to create a gmail account. I don't want a Gmail account. I don't understand why I need one when I've already got a Google account. I thought that would be enough info needed.

Comment: An Outlook account is not a Google account. Outlook is a Microsoft property. Is that the kind of account you're attempting to use during the configuration, or is it something else (like an account where you used the outlook.com address as a username, maybe)?

Comment: @eldarerathis A Google Account uses an email address as a username. For example, the owner of `chester@example.com` could establish a Google Account with that address by using the "I prefer to use my current email address" link on [Create your Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=accountsettings&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2F%3Fpli%3D1). This address would be marked as a Google Account without Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40656/google-account-without-gmail), there's no special hard requirement for gmail anymore. 
But `<`ics GoogleServicesFramework (or at least I tested version 2.3.7 that can seemingly only be found on some late-gingerbread stock ROMs) still expects that as "principal" one (ie use Play Store and GMS).

I guess like this shouldn't be too hard to solve by tinkering with the apk or accounts.db, but for the moment that's it.

Creating a totally new and dupe account, with your main "official" one as secondary (to keep stuff in sync) should work then. It's not really the most of simplicity or neatness, but if you don't want to *dirty* your account with gmail face, it's the only other option.

p.s. in 2017 you might get some initial crash here or there, due to very old vanilla applications. Making sure to install [this](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-10-0-84-release/google-play-services-10-0-84-034-137749526-android-apk-download/) and [this](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-6-2-02-release/google-play-store-6-2-02-0-2730934-android-apk-download/) solved everything for me.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly android is developed by google, so he make a stipulation into it that the android users had to have google account to make it work. So just make it one ;)

Comment: Android itself doesn't require a Google account, only Google's applications do. The initial account setup is generally skippable.

Comment: Google account != Gmail account. Google had an account system back when Gmail still required invites.